# boost::variant - How to assign values

Tags: c++, boost-variant

I have a boost variant and I want to assign values to it. 
The code looks like..

```
boost::variant <int, std::vector<int>,std::vector<float> > MyVariant;
```

How can I assign values to, int, vector of ints and vector of floats.
Simple assignment is not working.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far.  The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) seems fairly clear.

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working" ? Please include the code and the error messages in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty straightforward:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using MyVariant = boost::variant<int, std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>>;
    MyVariant m;
    m = 1;
    m = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
    m = std::vector<float>{1.f, 2.f, 3.f};
    return 0;
}
```

With a C++17 compiler you can use `std::variant` instead of `boost::variant`.